# Trying to find the most popular element of array

Tags: arrays, c, function, multidimensional-array, frequency

This is my last try. I tried to find the most popular element in a string, for do this i've taken the string and converted single character in number and after this i sorted them in int array.
the problem is: when i use the 2d array for keep the frequency of each number: x[1][y]. and which number: x[0][y]. for some reason they are trash number
can someone help me?
(my english is rusty, sry).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void bubble(int a[],int x);
void frequenza(int A[], int n);

int main(){
size_t counter;     
char a[] = "asrfujefwaa";
int b[20];
int x;
x = strlen(a);
for(counter = 0; counter != strlen(a); counter ++)
{
    b[counter] = a[counter];
}

bubble(b,x);

for(counter = 0; counter != x; counter ++)
{
    printf("%d ",b[counter]);
}
puts("\n");
system("pause");
puts("\n");

frequenza(b,x);
return 0;
}

void bubble(int a[],int x)
{
    size_t i;
    int ord;
    int scambio;
    scambio = 0;
    if(ord == 1)
    {
        return; 
    }
    else
    {
        ord = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < x - 1; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] > a[i + 1])
            {
                scambio = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = scambio;
                ord = 0;
            }   
        }
        bubble(a,x);
    }
}

void frequenza(int A[], int n)
{
    int x[2][n];
    int z = 0;
    int y = 0;
    size_t q;
    x[0][0] = A[0];
    x[1][0] = 1;
    for(z = 0; z != n; z++)
    {
        if(x[0][y] == A[z + 1])
        {
            x[1][y] += 1;
        }
        if(x[0][y] != A[z + 1])
        {
            y++;
            x[0][y] = A[z + 1];
        }
    }
    for(z = 0; z != 2; z++)
    {
        puts("\n");
        for(q = 0; q != y;q++)
        {
            printf("%d ",x[z][q]);  
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is `char a[] = "asrfujefwaa";` in the input?  Is `'a'` the most popular, or perhaps a better word, frequent, letter?  Can you use a 1D array?  It would simplify the logic.

Comment: @steno What is "the most popular" element of an array?

Comment: Do you need to sort the input?  There's a lot of complexity in your code that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @FiddlingBits i need to find in the string the most popular character. for do this i converted all the char in int and sorted them for simplyfing the search. my problem is in function: void frequenza  that i use for find the most popular int in array but in this code i need the excatly position of which number because after that im going to re-convert it in char

Comment: @FiddlingBits something in function void frequenza is wrong because all the numbers in second row is trash

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it's the more frequently character in the string

Comment: @steno If so then your code does not make a sense. At least you shall nit change the source string.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the most common character in a string, you don't need to sort it or anything fancy. Just iterate through the characters, recording how many times each one has been seen, and get the maximum such count. You can do it all with a single pass through the string if you keep track of the maximum to date as you go:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char a[] = "asrfujefwaa";
  int freqs[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { 0 }; // Initialize frequency table to all 0's
  int most_common = 0;

  for (unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)a; *c; c++) {
    if (++freqs[*c] > freqs[most_common]) {
      most_common = *c;
    }
  }

  printf("Most common character is %c, with %d occurrences.\n",
         most_common, freqs[most_common]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you,  i'm a beginner and i didn't know how to store the frequency and the char that's because i used 2d array. i seriously don't understand how this code work with pointers... but thank you very much

Comment: This solves the problem, so I'm giving it a +1, but I don't think OP will learn anything from just being given the solution.

Comment: @FiddlingBits i resolved the problem without help with my method. Because i don't know how pointers work in this code and it's the first time i see "for loop" with deference pointer as condition, and i never use <limits.h> header file. Can i ask you a question? can u suggest me a link for a manual or video or something else for learn this stuff. very appreciate

Comment: Learning how to work with strings through char pointers instead of array index notation is one of those "a-ha!" moments when it comes to C. (And thinking of a character as just another integer and not some distinct type of its own like in some languages is important too.) I gave a description of what the code does; with that in mind try stepping through the code in your mind or on paper.

Comment: @steno Perhaps I'm old, but I learned C through a book, Stephen Prata's C Primer Plus.